# Flutter: Why can't I create a new project and it freezes in Android Studio and VS Code?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, visual-studio-code, project

Why can't I create a new project and it freezes in Android Studio and VS Code?

Comment: What's your machine configuration ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.